# JOGL Immutable glNamedBufferStorage not supported yet on thread main-AWTAnimator

Tags: java, opengl, exception, buffer, jogl

I'm using JOGL for a game, but the following error is thrown:

> Exception in thread "main-AWTAnimator#00" com.jogamp.opengl.util.AnimatorBase$UncaughtAnimatorException: com.jogamp.opengl.GLException: Caught InternalError: Immutable glNamedBufferStorage not supported yet on thread main-AWTAnimator#00
>       at com.jogamp.opengl.util.AWTAnimatorImpl.display(AWTAnimatorImpl.java:92)
>       at com.jogamp.opengl.util.AnimatorBase.display(AnimatorBase.java:452)
>       at com.jogamp.opengl.util.Animator$MainLoop.run(Animator.java:204)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>   Caused by: com.jogamp.opengl.GLException: Caught InternalError: Immutable glNamedBufferStorage not supported yet on thread main-AWTAnimator#00
>       at com.jogamp.opengl.GLException.newGLException(GLException.java:76)
>       at jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.invokeGLImpl(GLDrawableHelper.java:1327)
>       at jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.invokeGL(GLDrawableHelper.java:1147)
>       at com.jogamp.newt.opengl.GLWindow.display(GLWindow.java:759)
>       at com.jogamp.opengl.util.AWTAnimatorImpl.display(AWTAnimatorImpl.java:81)
>       ... 3 more
>   Caused by: java.lang.InternalError: Immutable glNamedBufferStorage not supported yet
>       at jogamp.opengl.GLBufferObjectTracker.createBufferStorage(GLBufferObjectTracker.java:219)
>       at jogamp.opengl.gl4.GL4bcImpl.glNamedBufferStorage(GL4bcImpl.java:40826)
>       at rendering.Renderer.initBuffers(Renderer.java:182)
>       at rendering.Renderer.init(Renderer.java:128)
>       at jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.init(GLDrawableHelper.java:644)
>       at jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.displayImpl(GLDrawableHelper.java:690)
>       at jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.display(GLDrawableHelper.java:674)
>       at jogamp.opengl.GLAutoDrawableBase$2.run(GLAutoDrawableBase.java:443)
>       at jogamp.opengl.GLDrawableHelper.invokeGLImpl(GLDrawableHelper.java:1293)
>       ... 6 more

This happens when executing the code

```
gl4.glNamedBufferStorage(bufferName.get(Buffer.VERTEX), vertexBuffer.capacity() * Float.BYTES, vertexBuffer,
            GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

What's the reason this error is thrown and how can I fix this?

Comment: Isn't that error message self-explanatory? Seems that JOGL doesn't support `glNamedBufferStorage`.

Comment: This feature will be implemented, it's not a definitive limitation.

Answer (score 2):

It's a current jogl limitation, I opened a [bug](https://jogamp.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=1287) some while ago, however since Jogamp is going through some restructuration, things are not going to change in the very short period.

A workaround would be quite easy though, we should just comment [this out](https://github.com/sgothel/jogl/blob/45cc13c4d68fb3137b741cbc39ea653c15db2f66/src/jogl/classes/jogamp/opengl/GLBufferObjectTracker.java#L218-L220)

Otherwise, just use immutable storage with the old way school binding:

```
gl4.glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, bufferName.get(Buffer.VERTEX));
gl4.glBufferStorage(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer.capacity() * Float.BYTES, vertexBuffer, 0);
gl4.glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
```